# I hosted a site months ago using the gatsby tutorial, but now have no idea where it was hosted

Tags: gatsby

This is a pretty embarrassing ordeal.

6 months ago or so I hosted a site using the Gatsby tutorial and I tied it to my domain name. I did all of this through the terminal and somehow spun up a live site but its been so long that now I don't even know how I hosted it in the first place.

I don't think I actually hosted it with Netlify or Digital Ocean or any of those providers, as I have checked to see if I have an account under those names and nothing.

Does anyone remember the old Gatsby hosting/deploying docks, and know how I could have hosted my domain and how I could go about changing my provider. (I use Gsuite)

Comment: https://surge.sh/ ?

Comment: If you know the domain you might be able to do a whois lookup page. Otherwise surge.sh does allow you to host it completely from the command line very easily. Other popular options are Heroku maybe ? You might be able to look back to your email history to see that as well

Comment: Thanks! It might be surge, I will look into that. That looks familiar like it may have been that! I had looked through the email early on and was surprised there was nothing at all

Comment: @RyanBrown Could have been Zeit as well

Comment: @ksav it was surge, thanks so much!